# question about data model design in arangodb

Tags: arangodb, aql

**Update 2:**

The original question is too long, a simple way:

In [The City Graph](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Graphs/#the-socialgraph), how to query the city that can be reached directly from Berlin by `germanHighway`. I don't want the `internationalHighway`.

**Original Question:**

I now use ArangoDB to store a graph. I have one question for the data model design.

Use the knows_graph for example, [social_graph](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Graphs/#the-knowsgraph)

In my original opition, I think I will design two collections, the Document collection is `person`, and the Edge collection is `marriedWith` or `friendWith`.

But when I want to query the person who `marriedWith` someone, I can't filter the unwanted `friendWith` edges.(I'm not very familiar with the AQL, maybe this is not true).

In contrast to the examples in AQL Documents, it used to define a more common edge collection, for example, `relation` in `social_graph`, and define the more specific type in attribute. for example, `"type":"married"` as an attribute of a `relation`.

and thus in AQL, I can use `FILTER p.edges[0].type== 'married'` to filter the unwanted relation.

My question is:

1. Which method of data model design is better, or any suggestions for this?
   Now I think, put `married` as a type of a person, may be more flexible, easy to extend to `student`, `neighbour`... with one `relation` Edge collection.

   Otherwise, many Edge collections, `isStudent`, `neighbourWith`... shoud be created.
2. Can AQL could filter nodes by edge type but not attributes? Maybe looks like:

   `FILTER 'isStudent' edge`

**Update:**

I just tried, one relation can only used for two node type.

For example, one `isFriend` edge is used for `person` and `dog` nodes, then you can't use `isFriend` edge for `dog` and `cat`!

so many edges is must needed.

Answer (score 1):

For the original question:

1. If you have a finite, well defined, number of edges, then using multiple edge collections is fine specially if you expect to have a large number of edge of each type. If in the other hand, you foresee having to a large number of relationship types (friend , best friend, wife, etc) and the number of relationships of each type is not huge, then a single edge collection with a type indicator is fine and may simplify things.
2. The only two ways I can think of filtering edges from a traversal are:

   - [IS_SAME_COLLECTION](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Functions/Document.html#issamecollection) function. This will tell you if a document is of particular type. Keep an eye on performance if you use this in a big dataset though
   - Adding a type attribute in each edge collection that indicates what type of collection this is. Yes, it is basically a static field and is a bit of a waste of space but it works and space is cheap nowadays
   - Use anonymous graph traversals where you can define which edges to use explicitly

Having said that, Arango is a multi-model DB, and as such you could just ignore the traversal syntax, and just join the tables that you need, which would work just fine as well. It is the great thing about multi-model DBs, you use them in any way you need them.

In terms of your last update, you could check the edge collection by doing something like:

```
FILTER IS_SAME_COLLECTION('internationalHighway', e._id) == false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to design the data model depends on your business, If your model is more or less stable, and without many edges, you can select the `many edges` way, the edges is a finite set.
But I don't know how to filter by edge names :-)

otherwise, I think less edge and more attribute will be good.